# How to Override onListItemClick in a subClass

Tags: android, android-listview

i'm working on an app that im using ListActivity . inside im using AsyncTask and under onPostExecute method I set my ListAdapter . my problem is now i cant override onListitemClick for my list adapter . any ideas how can i do that guys ?

```
public class Category extends ListActivity {




/*@Override
public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setListAdapter(adapter);
}*/


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    jsonTask task = new jsonTask();
    task.execute(new String[] {URL});

}


    private class jsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(Category.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,name));
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
}
```

its only a part of my code and i just want to show my problem . it seems that its only possible to override in main class not subclasses

Comment: `it seems that its only possible to override in main class not subclasses` <= what do you meant by this? there are two ways to get it working override `ListActivity.onListitemClick` or setting `ListView.setOnItemClickListener(...)`(in this case => `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(...)`)

Comment: i don't understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setListAdapter ():

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new  OnItemClickListener()
{
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
 {
 }
});
```